# How check if has minimum one row in Select - PostgreSQL/Flutter

Tags: postgresql, flutter, supabase

I have 3 tables (in Supabase -> PostgreSQL):

```
posts(
   id_post INT,
   id_user INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(id_post),
   FOREIGN KEY(id_user) REFERENCES users(id_user)
);

users(
   id_user INT,
   PRIMARY KEY(id_user),
   UNIQUE(pseudo_user),
);

follows(
   id_following INT,
   id_follower INT,
   PRIMARY KEY(id_following , id_follower ),
   FOREIGN KEY(id_following ) REFERENCES users(id_user),
   FOREIGN KEY(id_follower ) REFERENCES users(id_user)
);
```

My query for the moment is `supabase.from('posts').select('*, users(*)').execute();`

The result will be

```
{[
   id_post : 1,
   users : {id_user: 1}
]}
```

But I want **to check if a row exist in follows** where `'id_follower' = 1` and `'id_following' = the user_id of the post`

So I want:

```
{[
   id_post : 1,
   users : {id_user: 1, isFollowed: 1}
]}
```

If the current user follow the user of the post, otherwise it will be 0.

Comment: You would need to create a database function for this. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions

Answer (score 0):

You can use match for filtering plus the count option.

```
const { data, count } = supabase
  .from('follows')
  .select('*', { count: 'exact' })
  .match({ id_user: 1, id_following: user_id })
```

I didn't find documentation for Flutter, btw I think the syntax is similar of the javascript one.

https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/filter#filter-embedded-resources

https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select#querying-with-count-option